# How to fix this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

What does

```
this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
```

mean ?

I getting this error while compiling at statement like this:

```
switch(eT)
    {
    case SEL_CRIT:
        {
            TYPE1* psSel;
            iRetVal = dbseq(enB->m_ps,
                NULL, NULL, &esM, NULL, ESEC);
            while (iRetVal == 0)
            {
                if(psEnterprise)
                {
                    bool iFound = false;
                    for (i = 0; i< psME->m_pslave[0].m_uc; i++)
                    {
                        ENT node1;
                        sEOS = psME>m_pslave[0].m_pslavecnt[i];

                    }
                    if (iFound && (psME->m_NOTOVERLOADED == false))
                    {
                        return psME;
                    }
                }
            }
            psSel = (M_EN*)pCrit;
            LOG_INFO(FAIL_TO_LOAD, psME->m_ONG, psME->EN);
            int_Enterprise = NULL;
        }
```

at

```
int_Enterprise = NULL;
```

where

int_Enterprise is some structure pointer.

How can I fix this?

Comment: give the surrounding code too please.

Comment: You should know how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) by now.

Comment: in modern c++, `NULL` should be avoided and replaced by `nullptr`. Oh, wait, the variable name suggests it's an int? then you may want to replace NULL by 0. Not that it will not fix the warning, but it will make the code easier to read and understand.

Comment: What programming language is this even? C or C++?

Comment: This is a part of large code base that I didn't touch for long time and previously written for older OS (like 9 years ago) which I decided to port to newer Ubuntu 18.04. So I am not really sure what has changed since then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have no `break;` at the end of your `case:` so execution will fall through into the next `case`. Add a `break` statement to prevent fall-through if that's what you want or add a `[[fallthrough]]` attribute if fallthrough is intended.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, precisely this is what I was missing.